# Should I Use append or the Assign by Addition on a string?

Tags: c++, string, append, concatenation, addition

The [Assign by Addition Operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) and the [`append` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) seem to serve the exact same functionality for a `string`.

Is there a heuristic for which one I should be using? I mean surely they are different... or at least were different at some point?

**Notes:**
I couldn't seem to find a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) duplicate to this though there surely must be one, so feel free to close.

Also `append` has overloads which also specify a number of characters to be concatenated to the `string`, if I'm only looking to concatenate a portion of a parameter `append` is clearly the way to go.

Comment: Well I guess as far as the standard goes the former's complexity is *"linear in size of `str`"* and the latter is *"no standard complexity guarantees, typical implementations behave similar to `std::vector::insert`"* for whatever that's worth

Comment: If you want to append just 1 char, `+=` is the way to go